# Understanding ctools_modal_form_wrapper

Tags: chaos-tool-suite

I am trying to get a handle on Ctools ajax modals and I am reading a lot of tutorials. In one of the tutorials (on https://gist.github.com/mrconnerton/1979037), I see the following code:

```
// Create a blank node object here. You can also set values for your custom fields here as well.
$node = (object) array(
'uid' => $user->uid,
'name' => (isset($user->name) ? $user->name : ''),
'type' => 'mytype',
'language' => LANGUAGE_NONE,
);

$form_state = array(
'title' => t('Add my content type'),
'ajax' => TRUE,
);

$form_state['build_info']['args'] = array($node);
// change this to your type node form
$output = ctools_modal_form_wrapper('mytype_node_form', $form_state);
```

I don't understand the function `ctools_modal_wrapper`. What exactly are the two parameters?

On the ctools API, it says they are `$form_id`, `&$form_state` but I'm not sure what

a) the form id is and where it comes from and

b) what a form state means? This might be a question on the forms API itself, and if so, please guide me to understand how this all works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a better explanation [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/14758/what-is-form-state-used-for) so I'm not going to explain much about the `$form_state` itself here.

To present a form, you have to use [`drupal_get_form()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/drupal_get_form/7) function that returns a render-able array of the form. 
To build the form, you need to give a form ID (to get the form API arrays) and the state of the form. Form State (`$form_state`) becomes handy when you need to store arguments, previous step values, and many more (see the linked post above).

Ctools modal forms has many basic features.

- Detecting whether JavaScript is available in the user's browser.
- Falling back to normal HTML forms if JS is not enabled in the browser.
- Keep form validation and submit functions working in the popup form.
- Executing certain functions when the form is submitted.

Here is an example of a full Modal form menu router item. Note that I'm not using `%ctools_js` menu loaders to make this simple:

```
function quotes_editform_ajax($form, &$form_state, $quote){
  ctools_include('ajax');
  ctools_include('modal');
  $form_state = array(
    'ajax' => true,
    'title' => t('Edit quote'), 
    'is_ajax_update' => TRUE,
    'quote' => $quote,
  );

  $output = ctools_modal_form_wrapper('quotes_editform', $form_state);

  if (!empty($form_state['executed'])) {

    // Add the responder javascript, required by ctools
    ctools_add_js('ajax-responder');

    // Create ajax command array, dismiss the modal window.
    $output = array();
    $output[] = ctools_modal_command_dismiss();
    $output[] = ctools_ajax_command_reload();
  }

  print ajax_render($output);
  exit();
}
```

**Explanation:**

```
  ctools_include('ajax');
  ctools_include('modal');
```

These functions will include specific ctools plugins for our use.

---

```
  $form_state = array(
    'ajax' => true,
    'title' => t('Edit quote'), 
    'is_ajax_update' => TRUE,
    'quote' => $quote,
  );
```

Here we build the $form_state to pass to the form builder function (`drupal_get_form()`. `ctools_modal_form_wrapper()` calls `drupal_get_form()`).

---

```
$output = ctools_modal_form_wrapper('quotes_editform', $form_state);
```

Here, we build renderable array of the form. But the difference between `drupal_get_form()` is that it's actually in Ajax response form. 
`quotes_editform` is a function that returns a form array.

```
function quotes_editform($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['name'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Name'),
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#default_value' => !empty($form_state['quote']->title) 
       ? $form_state['quote']->title
       : '',
  );
  return $form;
}
```

In this $form_state array, `ajax` and `title` keys are ctools-specific. The `title` will be the popup's title and `ajax` is required to Ajax-ify the form. 
Pay attention to the `#default_value` of the above snippet. If we are going to show an edit form, we need to know the existing values. So we send whatever we have to the form builder function.

Node forms are a little complex that there is a base form and child forms for each form. 
This form ID is same as what you receive as the third parameter in `hook_form_alter($form, $form_state, $form_id)` hooks.

You are free to store whatever in this `$form_state` array. 
`$form_state` array is passed to submit and validation functions so any of those functions can make use of those data.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed response! But I still don't really understand the line of code $form_state['build_info']['args'] = array($node); in the code I quoted. What is this doing? What exactly is the 'node form' trying to create (the type of form which you said is more complex)?