# Custom submission handler is not called

Tags: 6, forms

I have a form with a second button which should add new form elements according to [this page](http://lovewithbug.com/technology/drupal/how-to-use-drupal-ajax-form-for-multiple-fields-with-add-more-concept/). The callback does not get called though. The second button is set from the following code.

```
$form[ 'addTicket' ] = array(
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#submit' => array('asdf'),
  '#value' => 'Add Ticket'
);
```

Clicking it should, as of my understanding, call this callback function.

```
function asdf() {
  error_log( 'I was called' );
}
```

It is never called though. Why? Is there a way to debug this?

This is the complete code.

```
function WPD14_menu() {
    $items = array();
    $items[ 'WPD14/anmeldung' ] = array(
        'title' => 'Anmeldung zum World Photography Day 2014',
        'page callback' => 'WPD14_anmeldung',
        'access arguments' => array( 'access content' ),
        'description' => 'Anmeldung zum WPD 14',
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    );
    return $items;
}

function WPD14_anmeldung() {
  return drupal_get_form('WPD14_anmeldeformular');
}

function asdf($form, &$form_state) {
  error_log('asdfasdfasdfs');
}

function WPD14_anmeldeformular($form_state) {
  $form['buyer'] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#title' => 'Infos',
  );

  $form['buyer']['strasse'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => 'Strasse + Nr.',
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#default_value' => isset($form_state['storage']['buyer']['strasse']) ? $form_state['storage']['buyer']['strasse'] : 'Strasse',
  );

  $form['buyer']['plz'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => 'PLZ',
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#default_value' => '1234'
  );

  $form['buyer']['ort'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => 'Ort',
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#default_value' => 'There'
  );

  $form['buyer']['mail'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => 'Mailadresse',
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#default_value' => 'test@example.com',
  );

  $nTickets = isset($form_state['storage']['nTickets']) ? intval( $form_state['storage']['nTickets']) : 2;
  $nTickets = min(20, max(1, $nTickets));

  $form['nTickets'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => 'Anzahl Tickets',
    '#disabled' => FALSE,
    '#default_value' => $nTickets,
  );

  for ($t = 0; $t < $nTickets; $t++) {
    $form['tickets'][$t] = WPD14_ticketformular($t);
  }

  $form['addTicket'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#submit' => array( 'WPD14_anmeldeformular_addTicket', 'asdf' ),
    '#value' => 'Weiteres Ticket'
  );

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => 'Anmelden',
  );

  return $form;
}

function WPD14_anmeldeformular_addTicket($form, &$form_state) {
  error_log('Callback called.');
  error_log($form_state['nTickets']);
  $form_state['nTickets']++;
  // $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
  drupal_set_message($form_state['nTickets']);
}

function WPD14_ticketformular($nr) {
  $form = array(
    'vorname-' . $nr => array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => 'Vorname',
      '#required' => TRUE,
      '#default_value' => 'Vorname ' . $nr
    ),
    'nachname-' . $nr => array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => 'Nachname',
      '#required' => TRUE,
      '#default_value' => 'Nachname ' . $nr
    ),
    'frMain-' . $nr => array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => 'Hauptvortrag Freitag',
      '#required' => TRUE,
      '#default_value' => 'Fr H ' . $nr
    ),
    'saDay-' . $nr => array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => 'Nachmittagsvorträge',
      '#required' => TRUE,
      '#default_value' => 'Sa ' . $nr
    ),
    'saMain-' . $nr => array(
      '#type' => 'Hauptvortrag Samstag',
      '#title' => 'Name',
      '#required' => TRUE,
      '#default_value' => 'Sa H ' . $nr
    ),
  );

  return $form;
}


function WPD14_anmeldeformular_validate($form, &$form_state){
  if (!preg_match( '/^[a-z0-9]+([_.-][a-z0-9]+)*@([a-z0-9]+([.-][a-z0-9]+)*)+\\.[a-z]{2,4}$/', $form_state['values']['mail'])) {
    form_set_error('mail','Bitte geben Sie eine gültige Mailadresse an.');
  }

  $nTickets = intval($form_state['values']['nTickets']);
  if ($nTickets < 1) {
    form_set_error('nTickets','Kein Ticket ausgewählt.');
  }

  form_set_error('debug', print_r($form_state, TRUE));
}
```

Comment: It should work like that. Can you give us more code?

Comment: Full code added.

Comment: It seems I have found the bug. It is the very last line in the full code example, `form_set_error`, which is always executed, and all other callbacks are skipped.

Comment: You should probably mark your answer with the check mark to indicate this has been solved.

Comment: Stack did not allow this, had to wait one day ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `form_set_error()` call that always gets called in `wpd14_anmeldeformular_validate()`. This tells Drupal that the form did not validate and Drupal will not call the submission handlers.

Other changes you will need to make are in the `hook_menu()` implementation, and in the form name method. Here's what your `hook_menu()` should look like.

```
function wpd14_menu() {
  $items = array();
  $items['wpd14/anmeldung'] = array(
    'title' => 'Anmeldung zum World Photography Day 2014',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('wpd14_anmeldeformular'),
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'description' => 'Anmeldung zum WPD 14',
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
  return $items;
}
```

Note the change for 'page callback' and the addition of 'page arguments'. Finally, the arguments of wpd14_anmeldeformular are incorrect. They should be as follows.

```
function wpd14_anmeldeformular($form, &$form_state) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the additional information. Is there another advantage of drupal_get_form as page callback except for not requiring the additional function? (I'm going to need it to prepend some HTML etc, at the moment it is useless though.)

Comment: I think calling drupal_get_form in a page callback function, or using drupal_get_form as the page callback function, doesn't necessarily give a huge advantage. If you look at other menu items that return a form, drupal_get_form is typically used. You do have the option of adding markup to the form if that's the only reason for not using drupal_get_form. Using form #type='item', for example, is one way to prepend HTML.

Comment: Regarding the `$form, &$form_state`: When using it like that, I get a `warning: Missing argument 2 for WPD14_anmeldeformular()` and additionally a white screen when trying to submit. So, it only works with one parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a custom "#name" value to the button. Drupal defaults to having a name of 'op' for buttons, so it's likely thinking they're the same button and only calling the one callback.

Comment: Added a unique `#name` to both submit buttons, but it did not change anything.

Comment: No. But I have ensured drupal did not run outdated code. :)

Answer (score 1):

The bug was, as already noted in the comment, that the _validate hook failed and prevented all further callbacks. So, even for the custom submit button, the validate hook was called first.

Necessary changes were removing the last line in `function WPD14_anmeldeformular_validate( $form, &$form_state )`, changing the callback function as follows

```
function WPD14_anmeldeformular_addTicket( $form, &$form_state )
{
    $form_state['values'][ 'nTickets' ]++;
    $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
}
```

and use `$form_state['values']` instead of `'storage'` everywhere; [What is $form_state used for?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/14758/what-is-form-state-used-for) explained this.

```
$nTickets = isset( $form_state[ 'values' ][ 'nTickets' ] ) ? intval( $form_state[ 'values' ][ 'nTickets' ] ) : 2;
$nTickets = min( 20, max( 1, $nTickets ) );
```