# How to access individual items in $form_state['values'] post-submit

Tags: forms

**Question**

After a user has a submitted a form how do I determine how to reference individual form field values in `$form_state['values']` ?

**Examples**

For example, I have several fields in my form, such as 'field_organization' that would normally be accessed (for CSS) purposes, like so:

`$form['customer_profile_billing']['field_organization']`

I have others in my form that have even more convoluted paths such as

`['und'][0]['another-name']['a-fourth-name']`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can access `$form_state['values']` of a field in like

```
$variable = $form_state['values']['your_field_name'];
```

After saving you can access like this

```
$variable = $form['your_field_name']['und'][0]['value'];
```

For more information please check

1. [$form_state keys](https://www.drupal.org/node/1850410)
2. [What is $form_state used for ?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/14758/what-is-form-state-used-for)

Hope this will help you.