# Set a form element value to an empty string when it fails validation

Tags: 8, forms

I need to set the value of a form element to an empty string, when it doesn't pass validation.

I tried using the following code, but the form element still contains the last submitted value, when the form is re-built.

```php
public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $values = $form_state->getValues();
  if ($values['myfield'] != 'something') {
    $form_state->setValue('myfield', '');
    $form_state->setErrorByName('myfield', $this->t('Sorry, this field value is not correct.'));
  }
}
```

A workaround I found is using the following code.

```php
public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $values = $form_state->getValues();
  if ($values['myfield'] != 'something') {
    $form['myfield']['#value'] = '';
    $form_state->setErrorByName('myfield', $this->t('Sorry, this field value is not correct.'));
  }
}
```

Instead of calling `$form_state->setValue('myfield', '')`, it sets the value of `#value` in the `$form` array.

It doesn't seem the correct solution, though. How can I achieve what I want?

Comment: This is just fine, here is some [extra info](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/14758/what-is-form-state-used-for) on what the $form_state is and why it's used.

Comment: As for `$form_state` passed as reference: in PHP 5, objects are automatically passed by reference, without the need to declare the argument as passed as reference. Since Drupal 8 requires PHP 5, you will not see the hook argument declared as `FormStateInterface &$form_state`.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`FormStateInterface::setValueForElement()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21FormStateInterface.php/function/FormStateInterface%3A%3AsetValueForElement/8.2.x), which requires two arguments: the form element and the new value.

In your case, you would need to use code similar to the following one.

```php
public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $values = $form_state->getValues();
  if ($values['myfield'] != 'something') {
    $form_state->setValueForElement($form['myfield'], '');
    $form_state->setErrorByName('myfield', $this->t('Sorry, this field value is not correct.'));
  }
}
```

Comment: this worked for me

Answer (score 2):

In your `validateForm` you can use:

```
 public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

    if($form_state->getValue('myfield')!='something') {

        $form['myfield']['#value']='';

        $form_state->setErrorByName('myfield', t('Sorry, this field value is not correct.'));
    }

  }
```